# How to hide titlebars and toolbars in javascript button

Tags: javascript

How to display the pop up on java script button by using `window.open()` function without tiltebar and tool bars

I had tried using

`window.open("/apex/pagename?id=parameters","_blank", 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);`

it opens the new window with titlebar and tool bars.i want to hide that tool bars and title bar.

Can any one suggest the solution or an alternate to the above question

Comment: Please format your code, its very hard to read. Edit the post, highlight the code and press Ctrl+k

Comment: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3471181  This will help u

Answer (score 0):

Using your code, toolbars and titlebars were hidden for me (in chrome, which browser are you trying on?).

If you are looking to hide the close buttons as well, I don't think that's possible due to security issues, http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/79625/How-to-hide-title-bar-in-Javascript-popup  (feature no longer supported)

If you specify what are you trying to achieve, maybe there is an other way around, and popups are not really preferred. maybe what you want is a modal

Comment: I guess what you are trying to achieve is getting data from **/apex/pagename?id=parameters** and  displaying it on the popup, the HTML5 way to do it would be giving an AJAX call to recieve data and display formatted data on a modal using JavaScript . This method also have advantage that user doesn't have to unblock popups.

Comment: Check this pen, http://codepen.io/ramonigimenez/pen/rervxJ (thanks to the original author)  . Here, an external page is loaded on a bootstrap modal by using an iframe, Is this what you want to achieve?, If so I will edit my answer with necessary details.